# Efficient methods for developing cross-platform apps other than cross-compiling (Titanium) and hybrid (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, cordova, titanium

In the past I have built several webapps using html/css/javascript/ajax/php. Lately I have been interested in porting these apps to Android and iOS.

I have started using Appcelerator Titanium and I am enjoying it so far, but I would like to know if there are other ways to develop cross-platform applications for mobile devices.

I am already aware of the following methods:

- native (java / objective-c)
- cross-compiling (Titanium)
- hybrid (PhoneGap)
- webapp (html 5 / javasript)
- mobile web (e.g. mobile.twitter.com)

Are there other methods for developing cross-platform apps? What are the pros and cons of these methods?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options as an alternative. You can look for OpenMobster, Rhomobile, WorkLight, Pyxis etc. OpenMobster is open source and free. RhoMobile is free (Rhodes), but you will have to pay for RhoSync.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was looking for other methods for developing multiplatform apps. I am already aware of the following methods: native (java/objective-c), cross compiling (Titanium), webapp (html5/js), mobile web (http://mobile.twitter.com/) and hybrid (PhoneGap). Are there any other efficient ways to develop multiplatform apps?